# How are trailhead hands-on challenges checked

Tags: trailhead

What ways does Salesforce use to automatically check hands-on challenges against the requirements in hands-on challenges in Trailhead?

I've noticed that some challenges are checked by making API requests to execute Anonymous Apex that has some asserts checking the correctness. However, now I'm trying to debug an challenge that doesn't appear to be doing anything that is logged in Debug Logs. Does Salesforce always use the user with which I'm logged in to Trailhead? If not, which users should I turn on the debug logs for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, all hands-on challenges are verified by making one or more API calls, using the user for the selected playground you're in. However, not all API calls can be debugged. For example, describe API calls don't generate debug logs. If you're on a hands-on challenge that involves modifying page layouts, creating records beforehand, building reports, etc, then it is possible that you won't have any debug logs to help you out. In these cases, it's usually best to just start back from the beginning of the module and double-check your work.

Also, please read this recent [meta question](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2776). If you feel you are like 99% of the way there, and everything seems like it should be working, but it just doesn't, please do feel free to ask specific questions. However, in doing so, try to provide as little of the solution as possible so as to not give everything away, but as much as possible (include any error message, verbatim) so we can help you.